# Adding properties to an existing type with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

So I have a library written in TypeScript, which uses the NPM depenedency 'ldapjs'.

I also have `@types/ldapjs` installed into my project.

So in my project, I have this:

```
import {Client} from '@types/ldapjs';
import * as ldap from 'ldapjs';
```

Now here is my question - how can I add properties to a client with type Client?

I have this:

```
export interface IClient extends Client{
  __inactiveTimeout: Timer,
  returnToPool: Function,
  ldapPoolRemoved?: boolean
}
```

where IClient is my version of an ldapjs Client with a few extra properties.

```
let client = ldap.createClient(this.connOpts);  // => Client
client.cdtClientId = this.clientId++;
```

but the problem is, if I try to add properties to client, I get this error:

> 'cdtClientId' property does not exist on type Client.

*Is there some way I can cast Client to IClient?*

How can I do this? I have this same problem in many different projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While what you have added as answer might solve your problem, you can directly augment the `Client` interface and add the properties. You don't even need `IClient`. You can use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
declare module "ldapjs" {
    interface Client {
        // Your additional properties here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that wasn't so hard, I have been wondering how to do this for months.

```
 let client = ldap.createClient(this.connOpts) as IClient;
```

we use the `as` notation to cast a generic type to a more specific type (I think that's the right way to put it).

I figure this out via this article:
http://acdcjunior.github.io/typescript-cast-object-to-other-type-or-instanceof.html